# Best way to use mysql for docker based microservices

Tags: mysql, docker, microservices

I am developing microservices stack using spring cloud and database is mysql. for easily explain lets take one service and one mysql database.
my questions what is the best way to deploy mysql database to production for container based enviorment.

1. I can use mysql docker and mount host local file system to docker using

   -v /local/path:/var/lib/mysql
2. install mysql to host where docker engine runs and access that from docker. for that I can use

   --add-host="localhost:192.168.65.1"

however as far as i know i need to update mysql grants and to allow connect through this IP like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'username'@'192.168.65.1';
```

but since I am using AWS EC2 instance I dont know this IP is fixed or not.

is it good practice to update these grants?

from above two (or other ) what is the recommended way to use mysql for microservices in production.